# Creating menu in MVC Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, membership-provider

I am started new application in MVC 5.

Tried to create menu by using web.sitemap and SitemapDataSource. which is not working as expected and also found few documents which are saying that SitemapDataSource is not available in MVC5.

Can anyone help me to create menu list with respect to membership provider roles in MVC5 or can any one please suggest some helpful links for the same?

Comment: you are creating Menus asp.net webforms or asp.net mvc

Comment: @Saineshwar I am already having menu in web form application. Now as per new requirement I need need create exactly same in asp.net MVC application